# who forks when the applications are double clicked on Linux?

Tags: linux, exec, forking

So I know when in shell and I run an executable then shell forks it into a child process and later exec's to get the program and data memory of my executable. So if my shell is now closed/exited then all its associated child processes get killed as well.

I read that in linux every process is created via fork() exec(). Am curious, and was wondering whenever an application is launched by double clicking its icon, which process forks() exec() it, I understand it is some OS process, i was wondering which

Thank you!

**Answer**
traced it to /sbin/upstart

Comment: I would appreciate a reason for the down vote, this is a genuine question the answer to which I could not find online

Comment: I didn't vote, but I can tell you that I find your question impossible to follow as currently written. Perhaps others see it the same. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @Brick thank you! I might just have half knowledge at this point and hence, the incompleteness in the question. I read that in linux every process is created via fork() exec(). I was wondering whenever an application is launched by double clicking its icon, which process forks() exec() it, I understand it is some OS process, i was wondering which

Comment: Type `ps -fu <username>` on the command line. The column PID is the identifier for the process on each line.  The column PPID gives the parent process's number.

Comment: @Brick I did not think about doing that! Thank you! Traced it to /sbin/upstart which is the replacement to init

Comment: If that answer is satisfactory you could answer your own question and accept it. As for killing all children if the parent dies, it's not entirely true. It's possible to have zombie and orphaned processes on a system. Though they should (optimally) be rare. See also [this](http://linuxg.net/what-are-zombie-and-orphan-processes-and-how-to-kill-them/).

Comment: Yeah, that's absolutely not what's starting your applications.

Comment: @Seth I just read about that as well Thank you!

Comment: @DanielB if I am wrong can you please direct me?

Comment: It would usually be your desktop environment's shell or whatever is hosting the icons you're double-clicking. Try `htop`, it offers a tree view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a bit of ***terminology***.

An executable is a simple file in your system. A process is the nutshell which executes the program embedded in an executable file.

---

You are right about the ***way an executable file is launched***:

1. The parent process (already living) [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)s itself, leading in two execution flows from that point. One living in the parent process and one living in a fresh new process.
2. The new (child) process mutes itself to execute the program of the executable to run. This is done using a [syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) of the [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) family.

Taking the example of a graphical interface on which you double-clic an executable icon, you have your executable forked from the process showing the icon you clicked on with basically this source code:

```c
const char *exe_path = taken_from_icon();
int pid = fork();
if(pid == 0)
{
    // I am the new child
    execl(exe_path, exe_path, NULL);
    // exec only return in case of failure
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
// I am the graphical interface,
// Continue and wait for another clic
```

---

But the ***death and parentship*** of the child is not exactly as you say.

Basically ­—and when the parent process is still alive— the child process is the child of its father (yes!-)  It has its PPID (parent process ID) set to the still-alive process which forked it.

Things changes when the parent process dies. Child process continues to live but its PPID is set to a still-alive gran-parent process. There is always one since `init` process never dies.

---

The fact that shell children dies when the shell itself dies is something specific. I see two reasons for that:

- The first one: a shell usually maintains a list of PIDs it forked. And when shell dies, it kills them all. Major shells have a `disown` built-in command to remove a child from this list and let it live when the shell dies. See [bash man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SIGNALS):

  > The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP.  Before exiting,
  >      an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or
  >      stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive
  >      the SIGHUP.  To prevent the shell from sending the signal to a
  >      particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the
  >      disown builtin (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below) or marked to not
  >      receive SIGHUP using disown -h.
- The second one: shell children usually have their stdin, stdout and stderr connected to the shell itself via pipes. If the shell stop consuming child stdout (often to to print it), or closes its pipe end, then the child may have failures when writing to its stdout which may block or kill it.